# Command arguments in compiler configurations

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

[edit] I meant to say "command arguments in compiler configs" . for the title.

I am trying to get into game mods. And I am trying to implement the source sdk. one of the steps is to go into debugging in my compiler configurations and add some data to the command arguments

```
-dev -sw -game "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\SourceMods\firstmod"
```

Now I know what command arguments are. They are passed through the parameters of WinMain and judging by the name in the compiler configurations. I assume that has something to do with it. or maybe not. I am just not sure if the above would be considered 1 argument or multiple arguments. and what is it trying to achieve by passing a directory through. They weren't too detailed with the information.

Comment: Are you asking what the parameters do or how you should add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal (read console) C/C++ application you would have program entry point with the following declaration:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] );
```

Here `argc` is the number of command line "strings", including the command itself, while `argv` is the array of these strings. So in your example it'd be `argc` of 5 (adding the program name), and `argv[0]` is the name of the program, `argv[1]` is `"-dev"`, etc.

Now under Windows a GUI application is different - the entry point is declared as:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(      
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
);
```

So the whole command line (this time excluding the app name) is pointed to by `lpCmdLine`, so it'd be one string as you put it above. There are helper functions to split that string though. Take a look at these two entries on MSDN:

- [What's is `WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx)

  [How to get normal `argv`-style command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your example has four arguments:

1. `-dev`
2. `-sw`
3. `-game`
4. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\SourceMods\firstmod`

Because the last argument is surrounded by quotes, the Windows command line parser will consider it a single argument.

As for what it's trying to achieve by passing a directory, it's impossible to know for sure without seeing what the code does.  But one guess is that the build will generate multiple interrelated files that are all supposed to live in a single directory; so you specify the directory and all the files will be created there.

Comment: If I remember well the first arg is the binary path as on Linux. Which means 5 arguments not 4.

Comment: Do you mean "quotes" and not "parentheses"?